# How to simply test a local Wifi Connection to an IP, for example 192.168.0.100 with code status?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

Do you know if I can simply test if there is a WIFI local connection ? For example if the url 192.168.0.100 is reachable. I tried with the Reachability without success. It tells me that it is connected, but it is not true.

I would like first to test if there is a local WIFI connection, and then when I am sure there is a connection, launch that Web Service :

```
- (void)callWebService:(NSString *)url withBytes:(NSString *) bytes //GET
{
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        NSString *url_string = [bytes stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAppendingString: url_string]]];
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:timeOut];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; //try NSURLSession
        [connection start];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 192.168.0.100 isn't a URL.  It's entirely possible that the address is reachable but that there's no HTTP service listening.

Comment: I know that address is returning 200, and if i put some that doesn't exist like 192.168.0.101 that returns me 404. But if i use Reachability, it returns me YES everytime. So I would like to know if there is a way to have that status code ? I tried with an asynchronous nsurl connection, it works, but the problem is that it doesn't execute the connectionDidFinishLoading => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490047/connectiondidfinishloading-not-called-with-the-use-of-nsurlconnection-sendasyn/42490402?noredirect=1#comment72129076_42490402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConection have many delegate methods. try one of the following:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.download_connection cancel]; // optional depend on what you want to achieve.
    self.download_connection = nil; // optional

    DDLogVerbose(@"Connection Failed with error: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSInteger state = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if (state >= 400 && state < 600)
    {
        // something wrong happen.
        [self.download_connection cancel]; // optional
        self.download_connection = nil; // optional
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To test for internet connection you must employ Apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html). Check for reachability with the `ReachableViaWiFi` enumeration.

Then you will need to do a ping of your server. In your `didReceiveResponse` method you need to search for a successful reach of your server.

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSInteger status = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if (status >= 200 && status <300)
    {
        // You are able to reach the server. Do something.
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

"I tried with the Reachability without success"

Did you happen to forget to notify reachability to `startNotifier`?

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

reachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
    NSLog(@"Network is reachable.");
};

reachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
    NSLog(@"Network is unreachable.");
};

// Start Monitoring
[reachability startNotifier];
```

Comment: Thank you, I believed that there was a way with the asynchronous method. Reachability is not a good method to check a Local status code 200

Comment: Yes reachability isn't going to tell you if your response is 200 or not. It is just a utility class to determine network connection so that you can make a call to get a response at all.